# How can i remove link using regex in php?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove all links which matched this domain `vnexpress.net` in `href` attribute. 
This is a link example:

```
<a href="http://vnexpress.net/whatever">whatever</a>
```

This is my code:

```
$contents = preg_replace('/<a\s*href=\"*vnexpress*\"\s(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/', '', $data->content);
```

Please help me! Thank you so much!.

Comment: What regex do you have so far, and what error is it giving?

Comment: `href="\K[^"]*\bvnexpress\.net[^"]*`

Comment: @AvinashRaj i tried to use your code but it was not working.

Comment: try this `'~<a\s*href="[^"]*?\bvnexpress.net\b[^"]*"\s*>([^<>]*)<\/a>~'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's still not working. The links were still existed.

Comment: try hwnd's answer. It's the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked for a regular expression here, but it's not the right [**tool**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for parsing HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the html

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, 'vnexpress.net')]");

foreach ($links as $link) {
   $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$re = "/<a[^>]+href=\"[^\"]*vnexpress.net[^>]+>(.*)<\\/a>/m";
$str = "<a id=\"\" href=\"http://vnexpress.net/whatever\">whatever <b>sss</b> </a>\n<a id=\"\" href=\"http://new.net/whatever\">whatever</a>\n";
$subst = "$1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/25)

Comment: @Duy Nguyen If this answer works for your condition, then you may accept this answer..

Comment: This pattern will fail (because of the use of `.*`) in this kind of situation: `<a href="">text</a><a href="http://vnexpress.net/whatever">text</a>`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you improve it? and can you explain more (.*), please. I am new in regex, so i don't understand what it mean.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte   Yes, it will be `/<a[^>]+href=\"[^\"]*vnexpress.net[^>]+>(.*)<\\/a>/m`..  thanks a lot..